# How can I access a local sqlite database from a QML automated test?

Tags: sqlite, qt, qml

I have an application written in QML with C++. I have automated UI tests using Qt Quick Test written in QML. As part of a test I need to make changes to entries in a SQLite database via UI, and I want to verify the changes are made to the database using simple SQLite queries.

I expected to be able to do this using QtQuick.LocalStorage, or some other javascript SQLite library but am yet to find a solution.

QtQuick.LocalStorage does not seem to be able to open an existing .db file easily, and seems to be designed for storing temporary application data

SQL.js seems likely but as it is packaged as a sql-asm.js and sql-wasm.js, I can't easily import the functionality into my .qml test files.

e.g. following QtQuick examples:

```
import QtTest 1.2
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.9 as Sql

function test_database_connection(){
    var database = "../Database/d.db"
    db = Sql.openDatabaseSync(database, version, description, estimated_size, callback(db))
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Songs where id is "5" ');
    }
}
```

I expected this to open my database "d.db", and execute the query on it. Instead it seems to just create a new empty "d.db" somewhere and run the query.

Is there an easier way I can do this?

Comment: the first argument of `openDatabaseSync()` is a name of a database, not a path. to set a path different from the default one you have to call to [QQmlEngine::setOfflineStoragePath](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#offlineStoragePath-prop) before. Also the real file name is some hash of the `name` as I remember but that should be checked.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the command 
QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db= setDatabaseName(database);